# Set Label's text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a label's text using (document).ready method of jQuery library as:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j("#lblStatus").text("Must input EmployeeID");
    });
</script>
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label id="lblStatus">--</label>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.employeeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

HTML is:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j("#lblStatus").text("Must input EmployeeID");
    });
</script>

<h2>Search Employee</h2>

    <form action="/salary/searchEmployee" method="post">        <label id="lblStatus">--</label>
<label for="employeeID" htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }">employeeID</label><input class="input-validation-error form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-remote="User with this employeeID already exists." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.employeeID,*.id" data-val-remote-type="POST" data-val-remote-url="/salary/cnicExist" data-val-required="Employee ID is required." id="employeeID" name="employeeID" type="text" value="" />        <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
    </form><a href="/salary">Back</a>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2017 - HRMS</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

A very simple code but can't figure out why its not setting label's (lblStatus) text to "Must input EmployeeID" when document loads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not on your *document.ready* method of jQuery.
Your razor code could generate wrong html. You could try to update your razor code as below.

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Label("--", new { id = "lblStatus", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeeID, new { @class = "form-control" } )
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.employeeID, new { @class = "form-control" } )
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: I've edit my code above and made it simplest possible. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Please open Developer Tool of your browser, then access your page. Look at Console tab, is there any javacript error showing on Console Tab?

Comment: In the console tab(Ctrl+Shift+i), there is this error stating: "Uncaught TypeError: document.ready is not a function"